# UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT error

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm getting this error when trying to do embedded signing, but I have no clue where to follow as I'm re-using the data from the previous calls. The calls I'm doing are the following, with data and responses:

```
 --------------------------------------add envelope data sent--------------------------------------
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/467376/envelopes
{"accountId":"467376","templateId":"54E1223E-BE28-4216-B692-EB5D229063C0","templateRoles":[{"email":"natxo+1395913609@kodify.io","name":"natxo1395913609","roleName":"Signer1","clientUserId":1395913609}],"status":"sent","messageLock":true,"ActivateEnvelope":true}
--------------------------------------add envelope response--------------------------------------
Array
(
    [envelopeId] => 60683ae6-4934-4613-a7ff-5caf6e9145ec
    [uri] => /envelopes/60683ae6-4934-4613-a7ff-5caf6e9145ec
    [statusDateTime] => 2014-03-27T09:46:55.8047277Z
    [status] => sent
)
--------------------------------------get envelope recipients call--------------------------------------
GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/467376/envelopes/60683ae6-4934-4613-a7ff-5caf6e9145ec/recipients
--------------------------------------get envelope recipients data response--------------------------------------
Array
(
    [signers] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => natxo1395913609
                    [email] => natxo+1395913609@kodify.io
                    [recipientId] => 1
                    [recipientIdGuid] => 68e46f96-a745-493f-b160-7c3882e7081d
                    [requireIdLookup] => false
                    [userId] => 4d33efb3-4f6e-4d8a-ae42-8c4af58c2230
                    [clientUserId] => 1395913609
                    [routingOrder] => 1
                    [note] => 
                    [roleName] => Signer1
                    [status] => sent
                    [templateLocked] => false
                    [templateRequired] => false
                )

        )

    [agents] => Array
        (
        )

    [editors] => Array
        (
        )

    [intermediaries] => Array
        (
        )

    [carbonCopies] => Array
        (
        )

    [certifiedDeliveries] => Array
        (
        )

    [inPersonSigners] => Array
        (
        )

    [recipientCount] => 1
    [currentRoutingOrder] => 1
)
--------------------------------------get recipients view data--------------------------------------
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/467376/envelopes/54E1223E-BE28-4216-B692-EB5D229063C0/views/recipient
{"returnUrl":"http:\/\/www.fux.com","authenticationMethod":"None","email":"natxo+1395913609@kodify.io","userName":"natxo1395913609","clientUserId":"1395913609"}
--------------------------------------get recipients view response--------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using the **TemplateID** in your **POST Recipient View** request URL:

POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/467376/envelopes/**54E1223E-BE28-4216-B692-EB5D229063C0**/views/recipient

You should be using the **EnvelopeID** instead:

POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/467376/envelopes/**60683ae6-4934-4613-a7ff-5caf6e9145ec**/views/recipient

I'd also recommend changing the value of the **returnUrl** property and the **authenticationMethod** property in the **POST Recipient View** request, so that the full request looks like this:

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/467376/envelopes/60683ae6-4934-4613-a7ff-5caf6e9145ec/views/recipient
{
    "returnUrl":"http://www.fux.com",
    "authenticationMethod":"Email",
    "email":"natxo+1395913609@kodify.io",
    "userName":"natxo1395913609",
    "clientUserId":"1395913609"
}
```